# Is there anyway to change constant value in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, header-files

I have an algorithm written in `C++` and I am implementing GUI in that algorithm. The problem is that it contains constant value which is number of onu written in header file. I wants to take that input from user but I can't do that because it's a constant. Is there any way to do it. I have tried different ways but unable to do that. Algorithm is `Glen Kramer DESL` and I am implementing GUI in `visual studio`.

Please help me how to do that.

One more thing for clarification.
I cannot declare that as a variable because if I do so then I got an error due to following line.

`class OLT : public SimBase< NUM_LLID >`

Here `NUM_LLID` is that constant whose value needs to be changed. And the constant is declared in a header file included at top.

Comment: In the algorithm or code, change the constant to a variable; recompile.

Comment: 'I want to go the wrong way down a one-way carriageway.  I know means breaking the law and risking a serious RTA with high-speed traffic, but I need to know how to do it anyway'.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it gives error and the reason of that line is described above.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change a constant. By definition it is immutable. Use a normal variable declaration instead. If that would create a global variable (which is generally evil), make it a mutable property in a configuration class.

Answer (score 1):

If the code uses an identifier for the constant, you can change the constant into a variable:
**From**:
`#define PI 3.14159`
**To**:
`double PI = 3.14159;`

### Thorns

You will have to recompile and verify the code compiles without warnings and errors.

Some versions of C++ may not allow variables as array capacities:
**Old**:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
unsigned int buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

**New**:

```
unsigned int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
unsigned int buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; // May not be valid, depends on C++ version.
```

You will also need to review where constants are passed to functions.

Also, the change may cause the program executable size to change and the memory requirements to change.  For example, constants can be placed in the executable.  Changing the constant to a variable would require a memory location and instructions for fetching from memory.

### Switch statements

The C++ language requires constant literals for `case` in a `switch` statement.  Variables will not work for `case`.  The code will need to be rewritten.

Comment: Why would constants be passed to functions? They're constants...  ;-)

Comment: When passing an array, there should be 3 parameters: pointer to the array, the size or quantity of items in the array and wait..... the capacity of the array (which usually is a constant). :-)

Comment: Okay, I'll buy that. It sure serves to remind me of some of the advantages of self-describing datatypes, though...  ;-)

Comment: Why are you using macros instead of constants?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can write a wrapper method that takes constant from the user and internally write your own method by creating a new varible copying the user input...